# Multiplying Muti-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Been having a bit of trouble finishing this program involving two 2D arrays and multiplying them together. Now I was able to construct these arrays with set lengths and then using a number generator to create each array. As for a third array I was able to establish the length of the array, but when placing the three arrays into a method I am still having out of bounds issues.

```
public class arrayTest1{
  public static void main ( String [] args){
    int matrix1[][] = new int [5][2];

     for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.length; i++) 
       for (int j = 0; j < matrix1[i].length; j++) 
       matrix1[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);

      System.out.println("The array 1 is: ");
     for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.length; i++){ 
       for (int j = 0; j < matrix1[i].length; j++){
         System.out.print(matrix1[i][j]+" ");
       }
       System.out.println();
     }

     int matrix2[][] = new int [2][5];

     for (int i = 0; i < matrix2.length; i++) 
       for (int j = 0; j < matrix2[i].length; j++) 
       matrix2[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);

      System.out.println("The array 2 is: ");
     for (int i = 0; i < matrix2.length; i++){ 
       for (int j = 0; j < matrix2[i].length; j++){
         System.out.print(matrix2[i][j]+" ");
       }
       System.out.println();
     }

    int matrixSum[][] = new int [matrix1.length][matrix2[0].length];

    matrixMulti(matrix1,matrix2,matrixSum);

     System.out.println("The array mutliplied is: ");
     for (int i = 0; i < matrixSum.length; i++){ 
       for (int j = 0; j < matrixSum[i].length; j++){
         System.out.print(matrixSum[i][j]+" ");
       }
       System.out.println();
     }
  }

  public static void matrixMutli(int [][] m1, int [][] m2,int [][] totalMatrix){


    for(int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++)
      for(int j = 0; j < m2[0].length; j++)
      for(int k = 0; k < totalMatrix.length; k++)
      totalMatrix [i][j] += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the method? Can you provide the code?

Comment: My bad. I based the code of an addition program I was working on. I've renamed the method that brings in the arrays called matrixMulti.

Answer (score 0):

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` is caused by the fact that your `k` variable goes from 0 to 5. It needs to go from 0 to 2. The problem is because of the line :

```
for(int k = 0; k < totalMatrix.length; k++)
```

The matrix `totalMatrix` is initialized with `int matrixSum[][] = new int [matrix1.length][matrix2[0].length];` and `matrix1.length` is 5. So `totalMatrix.length` is 5.

To correct this you need to make sure that `k` is bounded by either `matrix1[i].length` or by `matrix2.length`. These two values need to be the same and you can choose either to be the bound for `k`.

So this is the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++)
   for(int j = 0; j < m2[0].length; j++)
    for(int k = 0; k < m2.length; k++)
      totalMatrix [i][j] += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
```

Also consider adding code that checks whether `m1[i].length == m2.length` and throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if not. If you are still in trouble have a look at [matrix multiplication](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Java).